# Account lockout policy with Samba 4

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, domaincontroller

I have recently been tasked with overseeing the administration of a small (<25 users) network that employs both Windows and Linux machines. The domain controller is a RHEL 6.4 machine running Samba 4.1.0 as an ADDC. So far, so good.

One of my tasks has been to create a policy that locks out user accounts if they enter their password incorrectly 5 times. Management insists that this functionality used to work, but hasn't for a few months. After doing some research, I see that `pdbedit` should be able to do what I want. Running `pdbedit -P "bad logon attempts" -C 5` seems to run correctly and inform me that the value has changed to 5. However, I reboot the domain controller and try to lock out my test domain account and it still allows me to enter as many erroneous passwords as I want and still let me log in.

Some more googling and I chance upon a `samba-tool` that seems to do many of the same things that `pdbedit` does. Running `samba-tool domain passwordsettings show` shows a few password settings that I can manipulate, such as `minimum password length` and `maximum password age` but nothing about a lockout policy. I change the `maximum password age` attribute from 60 to 90 days just to see if the changes manifest themselves, and they do. Logging into a linux box prompts me to change my password in 30 more days than before I made the change. So it seems that the domain is respecting password settings from `samba-tool` but not `pdbedit`.

Now I know that both of these utilities are "pointing" at the same database. Running `samba-tool user list` and `pdbedit -L` both show the same users, and adding a user with one utility causes it to show up in the other.

I have been banging my head against a wall for 2 days trying to get this lockout policy working. I am a developer so I am not very well versed in samba and system administration in general. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My smb.conf, in case it helps...

```
[global]
workgroup = LAB
realm = LAB.MY.COMPANY.NAME
# security = ads
netbios name = HOSTNAME
server role = active directory domain controller
idmap_ldp:use rfc2307 = yes
kerberos method = system keytab
name resolve order = host wins bcast
template shell = /bin/bash
dns forwarder = MY.DNS.IP.ADDRESS
log file = log.%m
log level = 1
winbind use default domain = yes
acl:search = no
client use spnego = no

passdb backend = tdbsam
idmap config * : range = 1000000-1999999
idmap config LAB : range = 100000000-199999999
idmap config LAB : default = yes
idmap config LAB : backend = rid

create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
force create mode = 0660

[all]

[my]

[shares]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you just need a newer version of samba.  I run 4.5.12 and have the lockout option from samba-tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am using samba version 4.7.6 and the correct command is:

```
sudo pdbedit -P "bad lockout attempt" -C 5  # (5 attempts)
sudo pdbedit -P "lockout duration" -C 1440  # (in minutes, for one day)
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks :)